# Chrome (55 and 57) on Windows 8.1 closes itself after a few seconds

Tags: google-chrome

I normally use Stackoverflow, but don't feel this question fits. I hope this is the right place!

I'm having some serious trouble with Chrome in that it suddenly shut down and now whenever I open it only stays open for at most 4 seconds. Then it closes itself.

While trying to fix it, the problem has become two-fold. The systemic shut-downs, but now (as described further down) Chrome can't even install properly anymore. It just shows me a blank/gray box with the Chrome logo, even after a "hard uninstall" with Revo.

I'm using Windows 8.1, and have tried both Chrome 55 and the canary build (v 57).

- I have tried reinstalling Chrome. Now after 5 re-installs (4 using Chrome uninstaller and 1 with Revo), a new problem has occured though. Whenever I open Chrome it just shows a blank/gray box with a Chrome logo in the bottom and nothing else.
- I have tried creating a new account on Windows, and installing Chrome in there. This has fixed a similar issue for me some years back. Chrome ran fine for 15-20 minutes, then the same problem occured.
- I have tried running without logging into my Chrome account (I read in an old forum thread that this could pose a problem)
- I have tried installing Chrome Canary. After running for some 10 minutes, it closes and the same problem is present.
- Based on asking this question in "Software recommendation" I have also tried complete uninstallation with Revo.
- Based on what I could find on search here, "Internet filters" could also cause this problem, but to my knowledge I don't have any (??)
- A complete system scan with AVG Internet Security didn't reveal any problems (it's always running in the background)

I'm not sure it's related, but both my desktop (where the problem is) and my laptop use the same Chrome account. The laptop just appeared with an error that Default/History is a corrupt file. But I assume a full uninstall would've corrected that? Anyway, maybe worth mentioning.

I ran Canary without extensions, without logging in or similar.

I'm running out of ideas :-/ Can anybody help me?